# How do I get the Add Content URL in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, freemarker

I want to get the URL of *Add Content* to pass to an AJAX call.
In my Freemarker Template I assigned this variable:

```
<#assign addContentUrl = theme_display.getURLAddContent() />
```

Then, I passed this variable to my JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addUrl = "${addContentUrl}";
$.ajax({
   url:addUrl,
   ...
});
</script>
```

The problem is that in the browser I do not get the URL but I get this function:

```
var addUrl = "Liferay.Dockbar.loadAddPanel();";
```

It is a bug of Liferay 6.2 or I did something wrong?

Comment: I can't find any documentation that tells you that `getURLAddContent` contains a real URL. So I don't think it is a bug. I guess it exists for historical reasons. What do you want to do with the URL anyway? Add a content object to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by including **`<#include init />`** because `theme_display.getURLAddContent()` is defined in `ROOT\html\themes\_unstyled\templates\init.ftl`.